# How do i paste data (which has no hidden cells) into a worksheet which has hidden columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to prevent data being pasted into the hidden columns in one copy/paste movement rather than having to copy/paste multiple times?

Comment: I have looked for that for years, I think "No, it's not possible". My workaround is to sort the target area so my target lines are all next to each other. Cumbersome, yes.

Comment: Hidden the same columns in the first Worksheet and then copy the whole Worksheet to the second one.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest comparatively the best & fastest method to Paste data by skipping hidden Columns.*

**Before Copy & Paste:**

[image]

**After Paste:**

[image]

**N.B.** 
As you can find the Macro has skipped the `hidden Column H`, while Paste data from Range `A1:C9`.

**How it works:**

- Hide Column/Columns, with this post `Col H` is  hidden.
- Either **Right Click** the **Sheet Tab** & from poped up menu Click **View Code**, or press **Alt+F11**, to get the VB editor.
- **Copy** & **Paste** this VBA code(Macro) as **Standard Module** then **RUN** the Macro **TestCopyPaste**.

  ```
  Sub TestCopyPaste()

  CopySkippingHidden ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C9"), _
    ActiveSheet.Range("G1")

    End Sub
  ```

---

```
Sub CopySkippingHidden(rngToCopy As Range, pasteStart As Range)

    Dim c As Range


    For Each c In rngToCopy.Columns

        Do While pasteStart.EntireColumn.Hidden
            Set pasteStart = pasteStart.Offset(0, 1)
        Loop
        c.Copy pasteStart

        Set pasteStart = pasteStart.Offset(0, 1)

    Next c

End Sub
```

- `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C9")` & `ActiveSheet.Range("G1")` are editable.
- Where `A1:C9` is Source to be copied, and `G1` is Target to Paste  copied Data.
- You may adjust cell references/Data Range also.